# Missing `$` like operators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

Below I've produced what I believe to be a summary of the standard `$` like operators for various classes in Haskell. There's some gaps however. Following the applicative pattern, you would think those operators would be `$$` and `<$$>` however I didn't see operators like that on Hoogle or Hayoo. Could someone fill in the gaps with the most commonly used operators for such gaps?

```
              | Function first           | Op   | Function second          | Op   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Plain       | (a -> b)   -> a   -> b   | $    | a   -> (a -> b)   -> b   |      |
| Functor     | (a -> b)   -> f a -> f b | <$>  | f a -> (a -> b)   -> f b |      |
| Applicative | f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b | <*>  | f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b | <**> |
| Monad       | (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b | =<<  | m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b | >>=  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: taking a cue from F#, sometimes you see `|>` defined for `a -> (a -> b) -> b`.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't one sadly. People usually use the left column with `.` instead of separate operators. I sometimes see people use

```
|> :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

as a pipe line-esque operator F# and OCaml like. Generally, however, people use `.` instead so

```
 a |> f |> g
```

is written as

```
 g . f $ a
```

This also applies to `<$>`

```
 a |$> f |$> g
```

could be written as

```
 g . f <$> a
```

This is actually faster (by a factor of 2x) since `<$>` can be quite expensive for large collections.

Comment: I've seen your `|>` spelled as `#` in a few libraries. Also, I'm surprised that GHC isn't capable of rewriting `a |$> f |$> g` as `g . f <$> a`, since it's one of the functor laws.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson GHC can't assume that you actually obey the type class's laws though. Somewhere, some (probably mean) person has a codebase relying on a broken functor :/

Comment: @jozefg Is there an optimization setting that makes GHC assume all laws hold? Because as long as you aren't using a bad library / relying on unlawful behavior (bottoms / the exact rounding error you get from floating point math) the program should work just fine (right?).

Answer (score 3):

The `lens` package provides these operators:

`(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b`

`(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b`

From the lens documentation on `(&)`:

> This is the flipped version of `($)`, which is more common in languages like F# as `(|>)` where it is needed for inference. Here it is supplied for notational convenience and given a precedence that allows it to be nested inside uses of `($)`.

Since 7.8 `(&)` can be found in [Data.Function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:-38-) too.